# How can set location for my swt file dialog?

Tags: java, swt

I have an application where i want to display swt file dialog but in defined location(i want it display somewhere down).I am not getting any method for that.Any help on this is appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the API doesn't support to set the location of the `FileDialog`.
But there is a little hack/workaround for that.

**All you need is to create an invisible `Shell` and set the location. The `FileDialog` decides its location based on the parent.**

It seems a bit complex to know the exact coordinates to `setLocation` on `Shell` but, I leave it to you to do some Permutations and Combinations to know them.

Here is the code which solves your problem

```
public static String openNewShellDialog(Display display)
{
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display , SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL); 
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    System.out.println(display.getPrimaryMonitor().getClientArea());
    shell.setLocation(616, 500); //It seems the location is relative to the center of the Shell w.r.t client area
    shell.setSize(0,0);
    shell.setVisible(false);
    shell.open();

    FileDialog d = new FileDialog(shell);
    String s = d.open();

    shell.dispose (); 
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) { 
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep (); 
    } 

    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't [`FileDialog#setFilterPath()`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/FileDialog.html#setFilterPath%28java.lang.String%29) what you are looking for?:

> Sets the directory path that the dialog will use to the argument, which may be null. **File names in this path will appear in the dialog**, filtered according to the filter extensions. If the string is null, then the operating system's default filter path will be used.

Answer (score 0):

When showing the `FileDialog` on top of a shell, you may open the file dialog, then get the parent shell's sub-shells (`shell.getShells()`) to find out the file dialog's shell. Now you should be able to change its location.